# Binding Button Content value in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to Wpf. Basically i achieve Button content Value change dynamically. here is my code.

xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="btnTest"  Content="NO" HorizontalAlignment="Left"VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="233" Height="40" Click="btnTest_Click" />
```

Cs file:

```
 private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {          
        if (btnTest.Content.ToString() == "NO")
        {
            btnTest.Content = "YES";
        }
        else if (btnTest.Content.ToString() == "YES")
        {
            btnTest.Content = "NO";
        }
    }
```

how can i achieve this same in "Binding" logic.

xaml:

```
  <Button x:Name="btnTest"  Content="{Binding ???}"   HorizontalAlignment="Left"VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="233" Height="40" Click="btnTest_Click" />
```

could anyone please help?

Comment: no.. i am using normal window class

Answer (score 3):

Just like this:

```
Content="{Binding XXX, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
```

This will get the value (for `Content` in this case) from `DataContext`.

EDIT:

**A)** To create data context (code-behind version):

```
this.DataContext = new SomeViewModel();
```

You may put this for example in your constructor (in control/form/whatever)...

**B)** And finally `SomeViewModel` is just a class:

```
public class SomeViewModel : IDataErrorInfo // sample interface
{
    private string _xxx;

    public string IP
    {
        get { return _xxx; }
        set { _xxx = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: what would be my Code behind?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
Content= "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=YNText, Mode=OneWay}"
```

and add this to the code behind

```
public string YNText {
    get
    {
        _switch = !_switch;
        return _switch ? "YES" : "NO";
    }
}

private bool _switch;
```